# Batch: Create a loop from a list of filenames

Tags: batch-file

I´m new to batch files and I need help.

I have a file with a list of filenames: **file_list.txt** -> content:"*file1.ppt, file2.ppt, file3.ppt*"

One file with some text: **text.txt** -> content:"*open xxxx and save as pdf*"

I need do create a new text file (**run.txt**) that will look this:

*open file1.ppt and save as pdf*

*open file2.ppt and save as pdf*

*open file3.ppt and save as pdf*

I have been looking into the "For" command but I clearly don´t know where to start

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (file_list.txt) DO (
  ECHO %%A

Comment: Is the content of `file_list.txt` in one line?

Comment: No, that was just a example, the text has 6 lines but just one string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set replace=xxxx
set /P text=< text.txt
(for /F  %%a in (file_list.txt) do (
   echo !text:%replace%=%%a!
)) > run.txt
```

Just put in `replace` variable the string that must be replaced by the file name.

Comment: Great!!! It Worked. That is what I was looking for. Thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your task?

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file_list.txt) do (
>>run.txt echo open %%a and save as pdf
)
```

Comment: No, the text "open xxxx and save as pdf" is just a simple example, I have various files with several lines of text. I have to define this text as a string also.

Comment: So, how do you know in _which part_ of the line the filenames must be replaced?

Comment: @Jose Costa: How about you change your question and tell us what you really want.

Comment: _So, how do you know in which part of the line the filenames must be replaced?_ I have to replace the word "xxxx" for the filenames.

Comment: @foxidrive: I´m sorry for not being much explicit, but I really don´t know how to put it on other words. I´m not a programmer and I have been reading this and other similar sites for four hours lokking for a similar question, but I couldn´t find it.